# change object pivot after animation and keep animation positions

Tags: animation, parent

I need some help. I have this truck... it is animated that it moves forward and do some other stuff... i animated the whole thing (3000 frames) but i didn't think about spinning the wheels when i was constructing it. I have set all origins into one point so i could move objects around and then back to 0,0,0.

The question is how can i make the wheels rotate around it axis (the phisical one) without breaking other animation.

I tried parenting wheels on empty object and than parant that on truck (so i could rotate empty object and it would rotate the wheel). It didn't work, the tires flew away during the animation.

If i just change pivot of each object they move to that point (red arrow on picture).

So is there a way to rotate tires around its mass without changing the pivot? Or to change the pivot of objects but keeping the translations and rotations like they are now?

Please help. If i go remake the whole truck animation it will take me like forever again.

Thanks in advance!

[image: spinning wheels truck]

Comment: You could try to measure the distance b/w where it is and where the new origin will be, then offset all frames with the graph editor to fix the animation.

Comment: Potential duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/802/28015 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object/1292

Comment: @pycoder cant manage to fix it with that bone tehnic... the wheel goes furder and furder away when truck move forward..

Comment: Why don't you just parent the wheels to the truck, delete their animation and change the origin? If you want to go back to 0,0,0, you just have to move the truck and the wheels will go back to 0,0,0 too.

Comment: That actually works.... I deleted all wheels animation, parented them to truck, then just add rotations for each child (wheel). still some work at corners but i think is still the fastest way. Thanks @MattFerndz

......... P.S. should i mark question somehow as solved? im new on this forum...

Comment: @Pajkec No, you don't mark the question as solved. What you would do, is accept the answer that solved your issue. In this case, once you expand on your own answer you would mark that as the accepted answer. Welcome to BSE.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted all wheels animation, parented them (the wheels) to truck, then just add rotations for each child (wheel animation).

Thank you @MattFerndz for the idea!

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail for future users.